# How to make a reusable Email task in informatica

Tags: unix, informatica-powercenter

My requirement is to send email to a user when there are no target rows for each session separately.I don't want to use user defined variables to map to the session properties.Can i develop a script which can directly use the inbuilt session variables and can be used with every session.

Answer (score 0):

You can put all this logic into the workflow, have a condition  based on the number of target success rows which if it equals 0, forwards to the email task which can also share this information

Comment: Can you please clarify it.How can the session variables be shared into the email task since they are limited only to the session context itself.Moreover,i don't want to create user defined variables.

Comment: Ok, so contrary to my earlier post  they're not in the e-mail task itself but they are available to the logic in your workflow connections so you can have 2 connections leading off from the session task, one connecting to the email task on the condition that TgtSuccessRows > 0 and the other connection leading to the next part of your workflow per your current logic. Also its not that much of a stretch to mail to a dummy mailbox at the end of every On Success E-Mail and setting mailbox rules to only forward the mails which contain the text  'Target Rows = 0'